# remove consecutive value from the row of particular column in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have dataframe:

```
       Date/Time        Category    Label
2021-03-15 11:38:03     A           label_90
2021-03-15 13:33:20     A           label_6482
2021-03-15 13:38:02     A           label_90
2021-03-21 11:38:03     B           label_90
2021-03-21 12:33:02     B           label_90
2021-03-21 13:38:02     B           label_90
2021-03-23 11:38:03     C           label_90
2021-04-16 11:38:03     D           label_90
2021-04-16 13:20:24     D           label_6482
2021-07-04 13:38:02     E           label_90
2021-07-04 16:38:02     E           label_90
```

I want to keep label which are occurring one after the other like `90` and then `6482` as the occur on the same date and with same category also and want to remove duplicate label.
Expected output:

```
Date/Time               Category    Label
2021-03-15 11:38:03     A           label_90
2021-03-15 13:33:20     A           label_6482
2021-04-16 11:38:03     D           label_90
2021-04-16 13:20:24     D           label_6482
```

I have tried using below script but it didnt work:

```
df=df.groupby((df["Label"] != df["Label"].shift()).cumsum().values).first().
```

Comment: "It didn't work" does not constitute a valid p problem statement. Explain your logic and what you were trying to acheive with that set of method calls, and how their results differ from the expected. "I copied some stuff off the internent" doesn't qualify either. Basic debugging and documentation reading are your responsibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `groupby` on both Date and Label and keep only the dates where there are more than one row:

```
#convert Date/Time to datetime if necessary
df["Date/Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date/Time"])

output = df.groupby([df["Date/Time"].dt.date, "Label"]).first().reset_index(level=1)
output = output[output.index.duplicated(False)].set_index("Date/Time").sort_index()
>>> output
                          Label Category
Date/Time                               
2021-03-15 11:38:03    label_90        A
2021-03-15 13:33:20  label_6482        A
2021-04-16 11:38:03    label_90        D
2021-04-16 13:20:24  label_6482        D
```